# Are there some figures for Moldova's economic benefits from their Association Agreement with the EU?

Tags: european-union, international-relations, trade, foreign-aid, moldova

Moldova has an Association Agreement with the EU which includes a [Deep and Comprehensive Free Trade Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_and_Comprehensive_Free_Trade_Area) as well as some ancillary benefits according to Wikipedia

> the modernisation of Moldova's energy infrastructure, and access to the European Investment Bank.

Are there some concrete figures how much Moldova benefits from all of these? How much tariff relief (absolute figure) did they get from the DCFTA? Do they have a positive or negative trade balance with the EU? Likewise, are there figures for what appear to be more aid-like loans or even outright non-reimbursable aid?

(If this is too broad, let me know and I can split it, but I didn't want to spam the question page with 4-5 questions about Moldova all at once.)